# Docker: what is the use of local volumes and some observation about volumes

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have the following docker file

```
RUN touch /root/testing

VOLUME ["/root"]
```

after i build and inpect and under config i see

```
        "Volumes": {
            "/root": {}
        },
```

after i run /bin/bash and inpect

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "fc1dc25de37d6d7593a21443cd2bef74a0a6a4e3276b8353199054404665c398",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/fc1dc25de37d6d7593a21443cd2bef74a0a6a4e3276b8353199054404665c398/_data",
            "Destination": "/root",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
```

When i start a container it creates a local volume and mount it on `/root`. It also copies the contents of `/root` into the local mount

if i do on the host we can see `testing` file in it

```
ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/fc1dc25de37d6d7593a21443cd2bef74a0a6a4e3276b8353199054404665c398/_data

testing
```

But the local volume will be destroyed immediately after the container is killed.

So what is the purpose of local volume. Because sometimes i if by mistake kill the container and still i want to have some data craeted by my container on the local volume, then its not possible since the local volume is also deleted.

I wanted to try named volumes.

I created

```
docker volume create test
```

then i my docker file:

```
RUN touch /root/testing

VOLUME [{"Name":"test","Destination":"/root","external":"true"}]

OR   

VOLUME [ "Name:{"Destination":"/root","external":"true"}"]
```

When i try to build i get:

```
Error response from daemon: when using JSON array syntax, arrays must be comprised of strings only
```

Then the only option left out is mount volume from command line rather than Dockerfile

```
docker run --rm -it --mount source=test,destination=/root archlinux/test /bin/bash
 [root@7c7001221c14 /]# ls /root
 testing
```

Now i check the test volume contents:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --mount source=test,destination=/tmp/myvolume archlinux/base ls /tmp/myvolume
testing
```

Here since test volume is completely empty so it copied the contents of the /root (i.e file testing) from the image when i do `docker run --rm -it --mount source=test,destination=/root archlinux/test /bin/bash` into the volume test

But if the `test` volume is not empty befor i `docker run --rm -it --mount source=test,destination=/root archlinux/test /bin/bash`: i.e

```
sudo cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/test/_data
rm -rf *
mkdir hellophp
```

and then do

```
docker run --rm -it --mount source=test,destination=/root archlinux/test /bin/bash
```

[root@7c7001221c14 /]# ls /root
    hellophp

So my observations are:

---- `VOLUME ["/path/in/container/"]`  will only create `local volumes` we cant use `named volumes` here

---- If i want to use `named volumes` then

a) create a  named volume

```
docker volume create test
```

b) mount the named volume into the container path

```
--mount source=test,destination=/path/in/container
```

------ *** Most important observation

***IF named volume is empty*** (no files in it) then after runnnig

```
docker run --rm -it --mount source=test,destination=/path/in/container IMAGENAME CMD
```

it will copy the contents of `/path/in/container` to `test` volume and then mount `test` volume at `/path/in/container`

***ELSE (i.e named volume has some file in it)*** then after running

docker run --rm -it --mount source=test,destination=/path/in/container IMAGENAME CMD

It will not change the `test` volume by copying files from `/path/in/container` to `test` volume before mounting.

It will mount `test` volume at `/path/in/container`. So any files existing in the `/path/in/container` will not be available in the container.

Comment: "But the local volume will be destroyed immediately after the container is killed.So what is the purpose of local volume". That's exactly the way it should be., dockers should not store anything. Volumes allow your dockers to be able to reach to, for example, config properties files, certificates, and so on. They also let you store in a common place. You share a common way-in, way-out to the host, and they let you "persist" data without persisting it directly into the container. But they are only useful at runtime, so...why would you need your docker volume to persist, if there's no docker?

Comment: I have postgresql container. I want my /var/lib/postgresql folder to persist, because i may have to re build and run the container, but i want to continue with my previous postgresql data.

Comment: `and they let you "persist" data without persisting it directly into the container.` : Is this valid for local volumes, since they cant persist data. 

One usage of local volumes can be if some other container wants to use the data of this container. Other wise for me to see the logs i can also see them using the container itself rather than creating local volumes.

Comment: What problem are you encountering?  Other than "don't use the Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive" and "consider host path bind mounts", it seems like you've explored the behavior of Docker named volumes pretty well.

Comment: I am not encoutering any problem. But i was confused. I found in one postgresql Dockerfile  `VOLUME ["/etc/postgresql","/var/lib/postgres/"]`. So i wanted to know what is the purpose or what advantage is there by this. My understanding is just some ease. We know the volume folders on host i.e in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` , so we can have a look till the time container is running

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a database in docker you can mount a local directory directly into your container using the -v option on the run command.

```
docker run -d \
-v <local path>:<container path>:z \
..
..
<your image>
```

The actual storage will be persistent on your local filesystem, and accessible in the container when the container is running.

Also read this
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/